# Calling a base constructor with two arguments derived from a single argument

Tags: c#, .net, constructor, initialization

I have a base class that takes two arguments in its constructor:

```
public class BaseClass {
    public BaseClass(string key, object value) { ... }
}
```

My derived class is constructed differently, using a single complex argument that I can then split into the base class arguments.

```
public class DerivedClass : BaseClass {
    public DerivedClass (string keyValuePair)
        : BaseClass( SomethingExpensive(keyValuePair).Key,
                     SomethingExpensive(keyValuePair).Value) { }

    private static KeyValuePair<string,object> SomethingExpensive(string input) { 
         // Do expensive things
         return new KeyValuePair<string,object>(derivedKey, derivedValue);
    }    
}
```

Given that I have no control over `BaseClass` and cannot give it a new constructor, I'm trying to find any way that I can pass along those arguments without calling `SomethingExpensive` twice.

---

I thought about using an `out` parameter to generate a new identifier for the additional constructor arguments during the first invocation:

```
public class DerivedClass : BaseClass {
    public DerivedClass (string keyValuePair)
        : BaseClass( SomethingExpensive(keyValuePair, out object _value), _value) { }

    private static string SomethingExpensive(string input, out object value) { 
         // Do expensive things
         value = derivedValue;
         return derivedKey;
    }    
}
```

But this is rejected in the current framework with the error:

> Error CS8107  Feature 'declaration of expression variables in member initializers and queries' is not available in C# 7.0. Please use language version 7.3 or greater.

Any alternative ideas?

Comment: How is the `keyValuePair` delimited in the string? You could use `string.Split()` to get the key and value and pass it to the base constructor.

Comment: @LewsTherin - If it helps with the analogy, imagine `keyValuePair` is a heavily encrypted string that contains `"key:value"` once decrypted, but takes roughly 10 seconds to decrypt. Can you come up with an approach to call the base constructor in 10 seconds rather than 20 seconds?

Answer (score 1):

I can think of 2 separate approaches, albeit not outright solutions:

1. You can cache the result of parsing the key value pair, so that the 2nd call is not expensive
2. You can use a has-a rather than a is-a relationship model. So that the base class is not derived, but a contained object, wrapped and exposed by the same interface.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Good suggestions thanks. "is-a" is definitely required in my particular case (e.g. I don't want to have to re-implement all base class interfaces as a pass-through) but the caching approach is practical, if not elegant.

Answer (score 1):

Just add an adapter class between `BaseClass` and `DerivedClass`

```
public class BaseClass {
    public BaseClass(string key, object value) { ... }
}

public class AdapterClass : BaseClass {
    public AdapterClass (SomethingExpensive se) : BaseClass(se.key, se.value) { ... }
}

public class DerivedClass : AdapterClass{
    public DerivedClass (string keyValuePair) : AdapterClass(SomethingExpensive(keyValuePair)) { }

    private static KeyValuePair<string,object> SomethingExpensive(string input) { 
        // Do expensive things
        return new KeyValuePair<string,object>(derivedKey, derivedValue);
    }    
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the thought. We can actually avoid the need for an intermediate class completely just by having a second private constructor in the `DerivedClass`. Wouldn't have thought of it without this suggestion though, so thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Inspired by @alex's solution, but without the need for an additional class:

```
public class DerivedClass : BaseClass {
    public DerivedClass (string keyValuePair)
        : this(SomethingExpensive(keyValuePair)) { }

    private DerivedClass (Tuple<string,object> arguments)
        : BaseClass(arguments.Item1, arguments.Item2)

    private static Tuple<string,object> SomethingExpensive(string input) { 
         // Do expensive things
         return Tuple.Create(derivedKey, derivedValue);
    }    
}
```